# How best to interrupt a zeroMQ poll method for cleanup and termination

Tags: c++, multithreading, zeromq

Writing in C++ I have a thread that uses the zmq poll method to discover when there are new events to process, which works fine. What I want though is this thread to exit while cleaning up nicely when there are no more events expected.

Rather than infinite while loop I could put a condition in there but it would require REQUEST_TIMEOUT_MS to get there. So my question is, what is the best method to interrupt the poll for program exit?

```
void * Requester::recieve_thread(void *arg) {

    zmq::socket_t * soc = (zmq::socket_t *) arg;

    zmq::pollitem_t items[] = { { *soc, 0, ZMQ_POLLIN, 0 } };

    while (1) {
        zmq::poll(&items[0], 1, REQUEST_TIMEOUT_MS);

        if (items[0].revents & ZMQ_POLLIN) {

            // process the event
        }
    }

    // clean up
}
```

Answer (score 4):

It is often mentioned that you can just destroy the zmq context and anything sharing that context will exit, however this creates a nightmare because that will delete the socket objects and your exiting code has to do its best in avoiding a minefield of dead pointers.

Attempting to close the socket doesn't work either because they are not thread safe and you'll end up with crashes.

ANSWER: The best way is to do as the ZeroMQ guide suggests for any use via multiple threads;  use zmq sockets and not thread mutexes/locks/etc.

```
Requester::Requester(zmq::context_t* context)
{
    m_context = context;

    // Create a socket that you'll use as the interrupt-event receiver
    // I'm using a random address and an inproc socket (inprocs need to share a context)
    snprintf(m_signalStopAddr, sizeof(m_signalStopAddr) / sizeof(*m_signalStopAddr), "inproc://%lx%x", (unsigned long)this, rand());
    m_signalStop = new zmq::socket_t(m_context, ZMQ_PAIR);
    m_signalStop->bind(m_signalStopAddr);
}

// Your thread-safe poll interrupter
Requester::interrupt()
{
    char dummy;
    zmq::socket_t doSignal(m_context, ZMQ_PAIR);
    doSignal.connect(m_signalStopAddr);
    doSignal.send(&dummy, sizeof(dummy));
}

void * Requester::recieve_thread(void *arg)
{
    zmq::socket_t * soc = (zmq::socket_t *) arg;
    zmq::pollitem_t items[] =
    {
        { *soc, 0, ZMQ_POLLIN, 0 },
        { *m_signalStop, 0, ZMQ_POLLIN, 0 }
    };

    while (1)
    {
        zmq::poll(items, 2, REQUEST_TIMEOUT_MS);
        if (items[1].revents & ZMQ_POLLIN)
        {
            break; // exit
        }

        if (items[0].revents & ZMQ_POLLIN)
        {
            // process the event
        }
    }

    // Cleanup
}

zmq::context_t* m_context;
zmq::socket_t* m_signalStop; // Don't forget to delete this!
char m_signalStopAddr[100];
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't interrupt the poll - send the thread a message instructing it to clean up and exit.